# Why $f$ preserve angles means that $f$ preserve radii ? (Proof of Liouville Theorem in Riemannian Geometry)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Picture below is from 5.2 Theorem of chapter 8  of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. I can't understand the red line. Why $f$ preserve angles means that $f$ map radii into radii ?

$U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set.  $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is a conformal transformation, but have not concrete expression. From equation (11), I have the diagrammatic drawing.

Besides, in my view, $f$ just be a conformal satisfy equation (11). But I'm not sure whether I'm missing something, so I add the all proof in pictures bottom.

> [image]

> [image]

> > [image]
> > [image]
> > [image]
> > [image]
> > [image]

Comment: I would guess more context is needed. The map $\vec{x} \mapsto \frac12\vec{x}$ preserves angles, but certainly not radii.

Comment: Here, I presume radius means a geodesic ray. But we need to know more about $f$. I suggest you write this question using your own words instead of Do Carmo’s.

Comment: @MPW  $f$ is a conformal  transformation, so it preserves angles. And the the radius are the radius of two spheres center at $p_0, q_0$.

Comment: @Deane  The radius are the radius of two shperes center at $p_0, q_0$. $f$ is the conformal transformation.

Comment: Is a radius a number or a curve?

Comment: @Deane  Thank you for your patience. I think it is a line segment. Since my English is poor, I add a picture.  For simple, I assume $p_0\in U$.

Comment: In the present form the question is impossible to answer: Moebius transformations (in general) send spheres to spheres but not radii to radii. Do Carmo probably has more restrictions which are not explained.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  This proof is a little long and I'm not sure I'm getting it right.  So I add all the proof. But in my opinion, except conformal and (11), I feel $f$  has nothing special.  Thanks you tell me Moebius transformations, I will to read it.